# Execute command After Login, LogOff, reboot, shutdown, Lock, UnLock in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shell-script

We need to write to a file, when the user Login, LogOff, reboot, shutdown, Lock, UnLock in Ubuntu 20.04 by writing to a file.

We have tried, but not working.
Not Found : /etc/rc.d/rc.local

None of the below url worked.
1 -> https://www.tecmint.com/auto-execute-linux-scripts-during-reboot-or-startup/
2 -> https://ccm.net/faq/3348-execute-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown-on-ubuntu

Comment: system already logs access of users if it is your goal. if not edit your question. If  you want the system to do special things at boot/reboot/shutdown you might change the corresponding scripts

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Our goal is to get how many hours, the user has used the system. For that we need monitor, when the system gets Login, LogOff, reboot, shutdown, Lock, UnLock. If these get logged, how to read these info from logs.

Answer (score 0):

then there are many methods to do that
first is to manage script at start/stop/reboot and so on... pig style

another way it to look around session log (/var/log/secure audit & so on) must script that until it is not easy to read.

or using tools that to that for you (you will have to improve that) :

```
for user in /home/* ; do last ${user#*/home/} -20 ; done > /tmp/analyzeresults.txt
```

working around a command like that (it reads the log files) should permit you to do what you're looking for

ALARM : it really looks like user work time survey ... in many countries this is highly illegal  you've been warned.

Answer (score 0):

Capture login: Create the following script:

```
/etc/init.d/Login.sh
```

Make the file executable

```
chmod +x Login.sh
```

Capture logoff: Place a script file in the path

```
/etc/profile.d/LogOff.sh
```

Make the file executable

```
chmod +x LogOff.sh
```

Capturing Lock and UnLock

```
gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 |
  while read x; do
    case "$x" in
        LockHint)
          if [[ "$x" == "$lock" ]] ; then
             echo "lock"
          fi
          if [[ "$x" == "$unLock" ]] ; then
             echo "UnLock"
          fi
        ;;
    esac
  done
```

Comment: Can you provide a hint of an explanation of how this works?  What are `$lock` and `$unLock`?  Where are they set?  If you know that `$x` *is* `LockHint`, why do you then also have to test to see what it equals?